# Position text in terms of figure, not data (absolute position)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Code & results below; I wish for the `t=5` in right image to be where it is in left image, for all `view` - so, position text on same absolute position, i.e. same relative to *figure*.

Python's Plotly allows this via `fig.update_layout(title={'text': 't=5'})`. `text(, 'Units', 'normalized')` and `'Units', 'pixels'` don't always work.

Can this be done?

[image]

```matlab
[X, Y, Z] = ndgrid(linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40));
D = X.*Y.*Z;
D = D * (100 / max(D, [], 'all'));

for ii = 10:10:100
    patch(isosurface(D, ii, D), 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'LineStyle', 'none')
end
text(30, 20, -10, 't=5')
view([3 1 1])
```

Comment: Try `annotation('textbox', ...)` instead of using the `text` function.  It's even the solution recommended on [Matlab's `text` documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-text-to-specific-points-on-graph.html#AddTextAndAnnotationsToGraphExample-7)

Comment: Of course you can also use `title(...)` same as you did in python, specifying a `'Position'` name-value pair

Comment: Before `annotation` existed, we used to create an axes object, make it invisible, and write the text to those axes. I'm glad we don't need those hacks any more.

Comment: It looks like you chopped some onions :-)

Comment: @BenVoigt `annotation` works, thanks! I'll accept as answer. (`title` doesn't work, however.)

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to **use `'normalized'` units for the `text` object**. This works because, according to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#f68-481090_sep_shared-Units), `'normalized'` units are

> Normalized **with respect to the axes**. The lower left corner of the axes maps to `(0,0)` and the upper right corner maps to `(1,1)`.

Apparently, the axes referred to here are not the "mathematical" (3D) axes of the graph, but the "canvas" (2D) axes of the rectangle where the plotting occurs within the figure.

So you can

1. create the `text` object with the default (`'data'`) units as in your code, and assign it to a variable;
2. set the `view` (this affects the relationship between `'data'` units and `'normalized'` units); and then
3. convert to `'normalized'` units, using the variable from step 1.

With this, the last lines of your code become

```
t = text(30, 20, -10, 't=5');  % step 1
view([3 1 1])                  % step 2
set(t, 'Units', 'normalized')  % step 3
```

##### Example

The second figure below was obtained by rotating the first with the "Rotate 3D" button. The text is in the same position relative to the window:

[image]

Or see this animation. The text remains static as the figure is rotated.

[image]

Comment: @CrisLuengo It doesn't move around. It remains fixed. I just included an example, but it's easier to see if you try yourself and use the "Rotate 3D" button. It think that the "axes" referred to by Matlab's documentation are not the "mathematical" (_x_,_y_,_z_) axes, but the "canvas" (2D) axes

Comment: Cool! I never new this was possible!

Comment: I need to rotate programmatically, and do so using `view`. This doesn't work, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: It does work. Please copy-paste [this code snippet](https://tio.run/##jY1NSwMxEIbv@RVzkSQlrcmuQmnpycWTNxH6QQ9hd6qBbbIk01r982vWFg9KwWEm5B0engk12SP2/WapYKVgvYUF@OY1uka0zqfO1ijGUzVVd1oq@M9KzlmVJcvJaDUZrc@hghEIozXcwt6eRCVmcuDYLkRwLgNGz75bM8jVWarfhEshHeJucFcqYwqqfI8/5sVDaEPkOThPGLvh9@Q8PtNHi0PwwSOXDH3DKNsJTyRKraDIMzb54bS453IOcAOJsAPDjg7fxaYEA2Yr4U9duIIlJEFZ8OIdpfOtuLet@8SGyx@uZJ09JBRGXsTFNfFv0FwF@/4L) on Matlab. Also, where does your question say that?

Comment: I see it's a bit ambiguous in terms of `view`, but I say `normalized` hasn't worked for me [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G1H1.png). The different `view`s are applied on different figures, not same - [example](https://pastebin.com/12Dzmfit). Also, I'm not notified of your replies with >1 responders.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon That text in your question was not very clear, I thought it referred to the Python code immediately before. My advice for future questions is that you try to explain it better. Regarding your linked snippet, you are specifying the text as data units with two different views. So of course the actual position is going to be different. If you want the text in the same position: temporariuse the same view in both figures, then set text units to normalized, and _then_ change the view in the second figure.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon [Example](https://tio.run/##xU@xTgMxDN3zFWaokpMO6dKKhaoTVSfEUpgQg8n5Wkt3ySlxW8rPHy6wISYGLNvys2y/5xQEjzRNHe8OmUyXMjDDCnxz@@mNAbURJewdl1QOucNAbl3rWA3rqga70cZd6lO2CjgK5fFS3XOkrZx7uoCYItnKUGzNkenknhfgwb9UYETJhN7ELZoa5hrXXpOV1Y2tlqaQOFH4FFnK16E8YM/v1FpdBvNfun/aDLY4EGCBV1I5dAWPNIwpY@aez3/585vaw/xX6od0AhYIGJUdwh7jjlozTR8)