# `annotation` outside permitted figure bounds

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) doesn't permit negative position, unlike `text`, but I need former to position [absolutely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77446494/10133797). Yet in below example, I need negative position (the text should be lower).

Is there a workaround? I suppose one could pad the figure, but I don't know how to, and it'd need to work for all `view` (text must remain absolutely positioned).

[image]

```matlab
[X, Y, Z] = ndgrid(linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40), linspace(-8,8,40));
D = X.*Y.*Z;
D = D * (100 / max(D, [], 'all'));

for ii = 10:10:100
    patch(isosurface(D, ii, D), 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'LineStyle', 'none')
end
view([3 1 1])
annotation('textbox', [.5 0 .1 .1], 'String', 't=5', 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are added to an `AnnotationPane` class, so

```
an = annotation('textbox', [.5 0 .1 .1], 'String', 't=5', 'EdgeColor', 'none');
```

Gives us the annotation, and

```
p = an.Parent;
```

Gives us the annotation pane.

You can edit the specific text positions for the text objects which are children of the annotation pane, although I'm not 100% sure how the textbox positions relate to the annotation positions:

```
p.Children(1).Position(2) = 0;
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `p.Children(1).Position(2) = -0.05` does it.

Comment: Be wary that if you add multiple annotations, they're all children of the same annotation pane. You might want to do something more clever to work out the correct index of the `.Children` property